# AWS EC2 Instance Public DNS without Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

Is there a way I can get Public DNS with assigning a Elastic IP in AWS EC2 Instance. I tried enabling DNS Hostname for assigned VPC, but no success.

Comment: Did you create a new instance after enabling DNS Hostname in the VPC? Changing that setting wont apply to any existing instances.

Comment: All elastic IP addresses automatically have a public DNS hostname -- zero configuration required.  What do you mean, "*get* public DNS?"

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, you answered my question.